# Regex for six characters with at least one digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex with at least 6 characters (no limit) including at least one digit. No spaces allowed.

I have this this regex:

```
^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$
```

However, I don't want to limit to 8 characters.

Comment: Please clarify: Are spaces disallowed thoughout or only in the first 6 characters?

Comment: no spaces at all. this is for password input. so 'abc123' is ok but 'abc 123' no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a regex with at least 6 characters (no limit) including at least one digit. no spaces allowed.

```
^(?=\D*\d)\S{6,}$
```

Or

```
^(?=\D*\d)[^ ]{6,}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jS4eP1/2)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\D*\d)` - Must be 1 digit (the lookahead is based on the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast))
- `\S{6,}` - 6 or more non-whitespaces

  *OR*
  `[^ ]{6,}` - 6 or more characters other than literal normal space

To enable the regex to match more than 6 characters, you only need to adjust the quantifier. See [more about limiting quantifiers here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

Comment: actually both of them are allowing spaces. i don't want spaces at all

Comment: Add the end of string anchor `$`. I thought you did not need full string matches, and now this is fixed.

Comment: What is the language/environment by the way?

Comment: Well, surely it will work with these natural languages. What about the computing language?

Comment: what is computing language?

Comment: Perl, JavaScript, Python, PHP, C#, VB.NET... Where do you use the regex?

Comment: Ok, I added the JavaScript tag. JS regex engine is much poorer than PHP one, so we'll limit to the one that has fewer features.

Comment: Jun  the regex works fine on my php pages but not on my js pages (i get lint error)

Comment: It is possible you are using the RegExp object. Then, you need to use double escaping. Or, use a literal notation: `var re = /^(?=\D*\d)\S{6,}$/;`.

Comment: sorry for all my questions.. i was ask to add restrictions to this type of characters : & + = ' so the regex should be - 6 characters, at least one digit, no spaces and no & + = '

Comment: For an upvote :-) `^(?=\D*\d)[^&+='\s]{6,}$`.You can add more unwanted chars to the negated character class. Hyphen must be at the end or escaped.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=.*\d)([\w]{6,})$`

I think it should work fine

Comment: An explanation will be welcome. Why do you limit to word characters only? Why do you use a character class? Why do you use a capture group? How is this answer better than accepted answer?

Comment: it would be good to be able to extract that word which is having the above constraints. you can add as many meta characters as u wish. i have used the \w so as to include the digits themselves in the search otherwise it will only match until it finds a digit(not including the digit itself).